# python3.0: imputils

Tags: python-3.x, python

Why was the imputil module removed from python3.0 and what should be used in its place?

Comment: Good question but looks like it has no replacement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [PEP 3108](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#hardly-used-done), it was rarely used, undocumented and never updated to support absolute imports.

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3.1, there is a module called [importlib](http://doc.python.org/dev/py3k/library/importlib.html), which should be a superior replacement for imputil.

Comment: Very nice.  I wonder why imputil was removed before adding importlib?  very strange...

Comment: Python 3 was primarily an opportunity for removing cruft, and imputil was seen as such (per PEP 3108, as @unknown says). To get a voice on such decisions in the future, join python-dev!-)

Comment: Just FYI, importlib is also in Python 2.7, its just missing most of the functionality available in 3.1 and later.